# Top Level Site SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

How many TOP LEVEL SITES can possibly be created in a particular SharePoint admin center? Not under/below the main site ,but as a new top level site?

Answer (score 4):

You can have upto 500,000 site collections in a single tenant as per the [Msft Documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

You have one Site collection at root of your tenant i.e `https://yourcompanyname.sharepoint.com`

All other sites collection under the managed path **/Sites** or **/Teams**.

For ON prem, their 500,000 personal sites and 250,000 other sites as supported limit. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0

Comment: good find, that's for online I guess on-prem is based on size

Comment: Yes, it is depend which version of sharepoint you but supported limit is 250,00) non-Mysite and 500,000 personal sites.

Answer (score 1):

When you say top level, I'm assuming you mean Site Collections because otherwise, there is only 1 root site collection not matter if you're On-premise or Online

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com
```

Below that you have managed paths

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/teams/
```

From Microsoft:

> Therefore, the maximum value assigned to the number of site
>   collections is not absolute, but is calculated based on an expected
>   set of usage characteristics in which overall farm performance would
>   be acceptable at the given limit under most circumstances.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits

Here is a handy guide I reference when wondering about SharePoint size and usage limitations:

http://icansharepoint.com/ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-size-and-usage-limitations/

Answer (score 0):

As Waqas said, the maximum recommended number of site collections is 500000 in SharePoint online.